# Simple Do-while loop in Java

Tags: java, do-while

I want to run a loop and continue to accept a string input until "x" is pressed. I'm trying following do-while loop, but it doesn't get in the loop, it runs only once.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;

do {
    System.out.print("Enter name or 'x' to quit: ");
    name = sc.next();

    if (name.equals("x")) {
        break;
    }

    System.out.printf("The name is %s", name);

} while (name.equals("x"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `if` condition so that it doesn't break out of the loop early and modify the break condition, e.g.:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;

do {
    System.out.print("Enter name or 'x' to quit: ");
    name = sc.next();

    System.out.printf("The name is %s", name);

} while (!name.equals("x"));
```

Answer (score 2):

It continues looping when "x" is pressed. So you did the exact opposite.

Add an exclamation mark to negate your while condition:

```
while (!name.equals("x"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but it seems like your code contradicts itself. 
You read user input and then check if it equals to x and breaks the loop in that case. If it does not, you continue until the while statement, where x gets checked again for the same condition. 
So in summary, you break the loop for the same condition you have for it to run.

You might want to try, changing your condition in the while statement to

```
while (!name.equals("x"))
```